# Fill hole in a raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, maxent, holes

I'm currently using ArcGIS Pro to process my Maxent output (habitat suitability). There's a hole in it and I'm planning to fill it with the nearest data. I've tried using the "Fill" tool but nothing change, my raster still have hole. What should I do to fix it?

[image]

Comment: "Fill" is something done to local depressions, not NODATA. You can use `Con` to mask NODATA, or to extract nearest values.

Comment: If you're using Fill then you must have a spatial analyst license, have a look at the tool Euclidean Allocation, that can be used to fill holes with the closest valid pixel.

Comment: it's fixed now, thank you!

Comment: What did you do?

Comment: i use the Euclidean allocation